# Winter 17 extending base LDS CSS not at component level

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, winter17

Why extends="force:slds" don't work at component level only at app level ? it would be nice to avoid static resource css.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_lightning_slds.htm?edition=&impact=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not see a use case actually why you need this at component level .

Lightning Experience - The App builder takes care of the styling .You do not need to worry about styling your component .SLDS is available inbuilt .

SF1 - The builder will take care of it

Communities - The app builder will take care

Visualforce - The lightning app is used and hence you can extend with force:slds

Lightning Out - The Lightning app is used and hence you can extend with force:slds

URL based links - Lightning app can be used .

That covers up all the scenarios .

Comment: Thanks I didn't read the doc for lightning out fully. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm

Comment: How about in Actions, as per Winter 17? I guess for this one we don't need to create wrapper app ? https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_lightning_component_actions.htm

Comment: I believe it is taken care since its part of lightning experience .From what i see in demos none of code had any additional static resource added

Comment: Ok, any lightning actions you create can't bed added to standard quick action in classic publisher only to S1 & LEX action section

Comment: yes .You are correct